# Daily countdown/timer with different starting times

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

I'm trying to build a daily countdown for specific time period. Example: Count daily to 3pm, from 3pm to 5pm show a Message, start countdown again till 3pm. For this I found already a nearly perfect solution here. It counts every day to the chosen time. But now I need different end times for specific days, like:

Friday - Tuesday count till 3pm
Wednesday - Thursday count till 5pm

the code so far looks like this:

```
var countDown = (function() {
                var startStream;
                var endStream;
                var streamingText = 'Streaming';
                var updateElement;

                // Pad single digit numbers
                function pad(n) {
                    return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + +n;
                }

                // Format a time difference as hh:mm:ss
                // d0 and d1 are date objects, d0 < d1
                function timeDiff(d0, d1) {
                    var diff = d1 - d0;
                    return pad(diff / 3.6e6 | 0) + ':' + pad((diff % 3.6e6) / 6e4 | 0) + ':' + pad(diff % 6e4 / 1000 | 0);
                }

                // start, end are UNIX UTC time values in seconds for the start and end of streaming
                return function(elementId, start, end) {
                    var now = new Date();
                    var returnValue;

                    // By default, run again just after next full second
                    var delay = 1020 - now.getMilliseconds();

                    // turn start and end times into local Date objects
                    if (start) startStream = new Date(start * 1000);
                    if (end) endStream = new Date(end * 1000);

                    // If now is after endStream, add 1 day,
                    // Use UTC to avoid daylight saving adjustments
                    if (now > endStream) {
                        endStream.setUTCHours(endStream.getUTCHours() + 24);
                        startStream.setUTCHours(startStream.getUTCHours() + 24);
                    }

                    // Store the element to write the text to
                    if (elementId) updateElement = document.getElementById(elementId);

                    // If it's streaming time, return streaming text
                    if (now >= startStream && now < endStream) {
                        returnValue = streamingText;

                        // Run again after streaming end time
                        delay = endStream - now;

                    } else {
                        // Otherwise, count down to startStream
                        returnValue = timeDiff(now, startStream);
                    }

                    // Write the time left or streaming text
                    updateElement.innerHTML = returnValue;

                    // Call again when appropriate
                    setTimeout(countDown, delay);
                };
            }());


            // Create dates for a local time of xx:xx today
            var myStart = new Date();
            myStart.setHours(3, 0, 0, 0);
            var myEnd = new Date()
            myEnd.setHours(5, 0, 0, 0);

            // Create UNIX time values for same time as UTC
            var startUTCTimeValue = myStart / 1000 | 0
            var endUTCTimeValue = myEnd / 1000 | 0

            // Run when page loads
            window.onload = function() {
                countDown('foo', startUTCTimeValue, endUTCTimeValue);
            }
```